# finally, нелинейность выполнения

Tags: java, исключения

Что позволяет finally изменять нормальный поток управления внутри метода? 
Какой задействован механизм?

Comment: поясните вопрос. finally выполняется перед выходом из метода. механизм обработки исключений задействован.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вопрос про реализацию механизма языка на низком уровне абстракции? Я не знаю. Но самое простое решение - опустить весь try блок ниже по стеку вызовов относительно обрамляющего кода, и соответственно при выходе(возврате) из блока отрабатывать finally.

Comment: @Tachkin абсолютно верно: речь про реализацию механизма языка. Никак не могу найти внятного объяснения этой "магии")

Comment: вот в документации вывод в байт-код компилятором https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13

Comment: @Tachkin благодарствую! как-то не догадался в JVM Specification заглянуть! может есть желание оформить это как ответ?)

Answer (score 0):

Ну собственно сам язык и позволяет.

Сначала выполняется блок внутри `try`, затем, если исключений не возникло, `finally`. А вот return по сути состоит из двух действий - помещения куда-то результата и собственно возврат из метода. В случае finally он оказывается между ними. По сути, вторую часть - непосредственно возврат - можно рассматривать как позицию закрывающей фигурной скобки метода - в таком случае диссонанса с `finally` не возникает. Кстати, можно заметить, что большинство ide позволяют ставить breakpoint на эту скобку и останавливаются на нём как раз после `return`.

Джавы под рукой нет, но вот гифка для шарпа:

[image: Скринвидео C#]

Comment: Гифка зачетная, спасибо) Breakpoint на скобку - классный трюк! Все же хотелось детальнее объяснение на уровень ниже, что там со стэком происходит, как оно вообще осуществляется на низком уровне.

Comment: @IVBORA, на уровень ниже я не знаю. У меня есть примерные догадки, которые я описал одним предложением про запись результата куда-то и последующее goto на выход из метода (которое в большинстве случаев можно соптимизировать), но точно не знаю. У джавы есть ещё фишка - из finally можно сделать return. В шарпе такого нельзя. Кстати, загляни в http://govnokod.ru/17995 - как раз обсуждение этого return'а (ну если отсеять постороннюю информацию и спам).